# How to pass orderby params to $wpdb->prepare()?

Tags: wp-query, sql, wpdb

When passing values like 'ASC' or 'DESC' to prepare like:

```
[...]
$order = 'DESC';
[... (the whole query)], $order); // (as a prepare param)
```

it doesn't work because the resulting query from something like:

```
[...] group_concat(p.id ORDER BY p.post_date %s)
```

Will be:

```
[...] group_concat(p.id ORDER BY p.post_date 'DESC')
```

While should be:

```
[...] group_concat(p.id ORDER BY p.post_date DESC)
```

How to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don’t need to use `$wpdb->prepare()` for `ORDER BY` clauses. `$wpdb->prepare()` will always quote your variables.

Supposing you receive the ordering in the request, you can prevent SQL injection by not using the user entered value at all:

```
$sql = "SELECT....";
if ( 'asc' == $_GET['order'] ) {
    $sql .= ' ORDER BY p.post_date ASC';
} else {
    $sql .= ' ORDER BY p.post_date DESC';
}
$wpdb->prepare( $sql , $value_parameter );
```